# Where is ocrmypdf executable after Cygwin installation?

Tags: cygwin, ocr

I followed [this page](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#cygwin64) to install `OCRmyPDF` on Cygwin.  I did so from a non-administrator account, so the process ended up creating `~/.local/` for the required files.  The following commands, however, do not yield any executable matching `ocrmypdf`:

```
$ find ~ /!(c|cygdrive) -name 'ocrmypdf*' # Nothing from Bash
$ python3
>>> ocrmypdf --help # From Python
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'ocrmypdf' is not defined
```

Where is the executable located, and how should it be invoked?

P.S. Full disclaimer: I am a Python newbie.

Comment: It's not in `~/.local/bin`?

Comment: No, the only file in there is `wheel`.

Comment: That's a complicated install document overall. ocrmypdf has a lot of dependencies including non-python ones. Sounds like you may be missing something. Did you check each of them?  I'd give it a careful re-read and try again. There was no information output during install to provide any clues?

Comment: I've used Cygwin for close to 20 years, so I doubt anything untoward happened during those package installations. There was also very little output from the two `pip3 install` commands for `wheel` and `ocrmypdf`. The only seemingly noteworthy output was about the non-administrator account, leading to creation of folder `~/.local/`.  I'll try to find out how to unintall those 2 packages so that I can retry and capture the minimal output.

Comment: I just assumed you had to install some of those packages as part of this rather than having added them 20 years ago (I sure don't have `tesseract` in my environment). And I don't have 100% success rate when adding Cygwin packages. Sometimes things go wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I should be been clearer.  I started using Cygwin many laptops ago.  The current Cygwin installation was last updated on the day that I tried to install OCRmyPDF.

Comment: I found [this `pip3 uninstall` page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524522/3230708). It showed that `ocrmypdf` was not installed, while `wheel` was. Rather than proceed with uninstalling `wheel`, I retried `pip3 install ocrmypdf`. I saw much more output than I recall previously. However, it failed because of a missing `openssl/opensslv.h`. I'm not sure if it needs to be installed as part of Cygwin; if so, different versions exist in `libssl1.0-devel` and `libssl-devel` packages. That is a different question. I feel that I should delete this question...

Comment: `pip3 uninstall ocrmypdf` yields `WARNING: Skipping ocrmypdf as it is not installed`. I captured the failed installation output and will go through it to find all files/folders that I need to remove.

Comment: An alternative is to just install the native Windows version since you can run such programs from Cygwin-based shells. The one sticking point is Windows paths vs Cygwin/Unix style paths. You probably wouldn't be able to do `ocrmypdf /foo/bar/my.pdf` so it would either be `ocrmypdf c:\cygwin\foo\bar\my.pdf` or `cd /foo/bar; ocrmypdf my.pdf`. Depending on whether you solve current issues or how much you care about those path issues it's an option....  Good luck.

Comment: Good idea.  I will consider that.  I like to avoid installing Windows apps on a whim, but it depends on my need for OCR.  Thanks.

Comment: For the record, in case anyone else fails to install this using Cygwin and wants to clean up, none of the folders listed in the output from `pip3 install ocrmypdf` existed. This is based on `find /!(c|cygdrive|dev|proc) -name '*cryptography*'` (replace `cryptography` with any other uncommon folder name shown in the output). It could be that `pip3 uninstall wheel` and `pip3 uninstall ocrmypdf` got rid of them.

Comment: Folder `~/.cache/pip` does contain subfolders `2021-01-11 22:51 http`, `2021-01-10 14:32 selfcheck`, `2021-01-11 22:53 wheels`, which are likely from the `pip3` commands. This based on their names and time stamps, as well as the fact that I don't otherwise use Cygwin's Python on this laptop.  Since I removed `wheel` and `ocrmypdf` is apparently not installed, I feel that I can safely remove everything in `~/.cache/pip`, which takes 17MB.